# Tablesorter - activating a setFilter

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, tablesorter

Use case: csv file to be loaded into a html table which can then be filtered using arguments passed via the url (eg www.example.com?user=joe -- in this case joe is the filter).

I combined these two stackoverflow questions and answers [csvtotable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656696/jquery-tablesorter-dynamically-load-csv) and [adding a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649475/pre-filter-in-tablesorter) but all that happens is the url argument appears in the column's filter box but is not applied - you need to press enter in the filter box for it take effect.  I want it to be applied without user involvement.

I have installed all the js files from [here](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) so hopefully they are compatible.

Here is my pattern matched code.  Any ideas, hints or suggestions?  Thanks

```html
<head>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" >

</head>

<script src="/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.csvToTable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="TSVTable2"></div>

<script>

//get the agrument from the url
function getURLParameter(name) {
  return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
}

var username = getURLParameter('user');
//create the filter for column 7 (zero indexed) using the url arg
var filters = [];
filters[7] = username;

//csv to html table
$('#TSVTable2')
    .CSVToTable('/tmp/set-table_output.tsv', {
        startLine: 0,
        loadingText: 'Loading TSV Data...',
        separator: "\t"
    })

    .bind("loadComplete",function() {
        $('#TSVTable2').find('table')
            .tablesorter({
                widgets: ['filter'],
                initialized: function (table) {
                        //apply the filter
                        $.tablesorter.setFilters( table, filters, true);
                }
           })
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Maybe try wrapping the `$.tablesorter.setFilters` in a setTimeout with 1 ms delay. I don't have time to set up a demo...

Comment: @Mottie Altering the code to add a setTimeout wrapper did not change the behaviour  `.bind("loadComplete",function() {  
        $('#TSVTable2').find('table')
            .tablesorter({
                widgets: ['filter'],
                initialized: function (table) {
                        //apply the filter
                        setTimeout(function() {
                        $.tablesorter.setFilters( table, filters, true );
                        }, 1);
                }
           })
    });`